# Как отправлять запрос с периодом 5 сек?

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Помогите пожалуйста отправлять запрос на сервер с периодом 5 сек. Сейчас мой запрос отрабатывает, но только один раз.

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { };

  getUserTasks(userId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_tasks/user_tasks?user_id=' + userId);
  };

}
```

component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let userId = 1;
    this.getUserTasks(userId);
  }

  private getUserTasks(userId): void {  
    this.tasksService.getUserTasks(userId).subscribe(
      data => {   
        this.userTasks = JSON.parse(data);                 
        console.log('userTasks', this.userTasks);
      }
    )
  };
```

Comment: За что вы так не любите чей то сервер? Вы понимаете что если у вас на бекенде не слишком производительный фраемворк то это натуральный DDoS. Почитайте про COMET или websockets

Comment: один запрос в 5 сек это не большая нагрузка

Comment: А 10 000 пользователей отправляющих 200 запросов в секунду? Я не знаю вашего кейса, однако это не самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: "Я не знаю вашего кейса" вот это ключевое. преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол

Comment: Разумную архитектуру не стоит путать с оптимизацией.